# Graded rings and modules - which book to refer to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, graded-modules, graded-rings

Could you recommend a book with a good treatment of the theory of graded rings and modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Năstăsescu and van Oystaeyen wrote two books, "Graded and Filtered Rings and Modules" and the more recent "Methods of Graded Rings". Even if you don't want to read the more specialised material in them, the first chapter of the former and the first two of the latter contain a fairly comprehensive introduction for most purposes.

Answer (score 1):

These notes, book, and article:

1) [*GRADED RINGS AND MODULES* by *Tom Marley*](http://www.math.unl.edu/~tmarley1/905notes.pdf)

2)  [Graded Rings](http://www.math.unl.edu/~s-llynch1/RCNotes%20F07.pdf)

3) [*The category of graded modules* by *Fossum-Foxby*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fojs.statsbiblioteket.dk%2Findex.php%2Fmath%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F11553%2F9569&ei=agcbU_SrKYPXtAaqo4GwBw&usg=AFQjCNEEoe23Dp2LRqnkVvEYxmLZYLVEHA&sig2=K4cU4fPHxGT6-IkeyMcyMQ&bvm=bv.62578216,d.Yms)

and the best for me:

section 1.5 of *Bruns-Herzog*'s famous book: *Cohen-Macaulay rings*.